# How to move widgwts to next row in a layout PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, qlayout

I want to move widgets to next row according to resizing space.Suppose there is 5 label in a row ,but when i resize and there is insufficient size for them some of them will move to next row.

But I don't know how to achieve that using any Qlayout.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

I have done this manually but I want they should be automatically moved to next row accordingly while resizing if there is insufficient size for a element.

Comment: You might want to look at the [flow layout example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html).  Or do the widgets all need to be aligned in a grid?

Comment: Yes , U r right.This is the problem with PyQt. I am using Designer & there is no Flowlayout implicitly.So I was unaware of it. Flow layout is completely out of my mind.

Comment: This link already posted the solution.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60398756/pyqt-oriented-flow-layout